# Update Property in List of objects based from a list of ids

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

Two lists. One is a object representing a group of people I sent a email to. For brevity lets say the structure is

```
public class EmailSent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public bool HasResponse {get;set;}
}
```

That has a backing table of every email I've sent (minus the HasResponse column). I have another table that stores all the responses.

```
public class EmailResponse
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Response {get;set;}
}
```

I have a test that is currently failing and I can't figure out how to get it to pass. In production I basically query the EmailSent table with something like `SELECT Id, Email from EmailSent where Id between  @MinId and @MaxId`
Nothing fancy there. My test basically does a yield return that does a single EmailSent between each of those numbers... The next part is that I do a select on that list to give me the Id's and make a second query to the EmailResponse. `SELECT Id from EmailResponse WHERE Id in (...generate list of id's)` In my test I write

```
public IEnumerable<EmailResponse> GetEmailResponses(IEnumerable<long> Ids, int waveId)
{
    foreach (var id in Ids.Take(10))
    {
        yield return new EmailResponse {Id = id};
    }
}
```

The test that is failling is this

```
   [Test]
    public void WhenAnEmailGroupIsSelectedSpecificInformationIsShown()
    {
        _viewModel.SelectedEmailGroup = _viewModel.EmailGroups[0];
        _viewModel.Emails.Count.Should().Be(286);
        _viewModel.Emails.Count(x => x.HasMatchingResult).Should().Be(10);
    }
```

it's failling with error message, expected 10 for the count, but found 0. What I have in place right now is (changed var to IEnumerable for clarity)

```
IEnumerable<EmailGroup> emails = _dao.GetEmailsSent(SelectedEmailGroup);
IEnumerable<EmailResponse> results = _dao.GetEmailResponses(emails.Select(x => x.Id), SelectedEmailGroup.WaveId);
IEnumerable<EmailGroup> matches = emails.Join(results, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x).ToList();
//matches.ForEach(x => x.HasMatchingResult = true); this is the line that probably needs to change
foreach (var email in emails)
{
    Emails.Add(email);
}
```

it's obvious to me what is wrong, but i can't figure out how to easily update emails based on responses. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you do not have a `ToList()` on making `emails` `IEnumerable`, meaning that it would be re-generated again when your unit tests ask for it. At this point the `HasMatchingResult` flag would be lost, so your tests would fail. Fixing this one is easy - simply add `ToList` to the call that makes `emails`, and uncomment your `ForEach`:

```
IEnumerable<EmailGroup> emails = _dao.GetEmailsSent(SelectedEmailGroup).ToList();
```

You do not need to perform a join there: all you have to do is picking `EmailGroup`s that have matching `Id`s among the `responces`:

```
ISet<int> emailIdsWithResponses = new HashSet<int>(results.Select(r => r.Id));
IEnumerable<EmailGroup> matches = emails.Where(e => emailIdsWithResponses.Contains(e.Id)).ToList();
```

At this point you can call your `ForEach`, or better yet walk through the items in a "plain" `foreach` loop, setting their `HasMatchingResult` flags:

```
foreach (var e in matches) {
    e.HasMatchingResult = true;
}
```

Comment: ugh ugh ugh... :) you just had to make it look sooo easy. Thank you very much. I guess I should put my keyboard down as my nose is too close right now.